# Chaining Queries in Django

Tags: django

I am building a data processing app which allows user to upload multiple excel sheets, which is processed and returned back to user. I have created 3 models - 1st model is overall, 2nd model is capturing individual excel workbooks, in the 3rd model excel workbooks are opened and data for each excel sheet (sheets within workbooks) is captured. I need advise on 3 things:

1. Is my model structure efficient given that users will be uploading multiple excel sheets?
2. Given that users may do upload multiple times in a day, how do I retrieve the latest batch of files for processing?
3. I need to take user inputs against each sheet uploaded by user (3rd model) in a single view while parallelly showing a preview of the table to the user?

Please help with your opinions.

```
class UserUpload(models.Model):
    number_of_workbooks = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    file_size = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False,blank=False)
    multiple_sheets = models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)
    var_1 = models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)

class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file_field = models.FileField(blank=False,upload_to=user_directory_path)
    userupload = models.ForeignKey(UserUpload,related_name='user_uploads',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class FileSheetData(models.Model):
    fileupload = models.ForeignKey(FileUpload,related_name='file_sheets',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sheetname = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=256)
    var_2 = models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)
    var_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research I was able to get answers to some of the problems above -

1. In case you want to allow multiple file uploads you would need to create a separate model and link it with the parent model through foreign key. So my model structure for multiple file uploads is fine.
2. In my example, I have 3 models which are sequentially linked by a Foreign Key. Instances in FileSheetData can be accessed by following the relationship backwards. Here is the link to the documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects
3. I am still struggling with this but understand as of now that ModelFormSet could be a potential way to solve it but I am working on it.